# Passagem de valor de variável obtida em um método para outro método em Java

Tags: java, variáveis, método, passagem-por-valor

O projeto se trata de um GED escolar, onde há a classe principal que faz a conexão com banco de dados e há uma outra classe para gerar arquivos em PDF.

A questão é que o sistema chega a extrair o dado desejado do banco de dados, porém não consegue inseri-lo no arquivo PDF.

Vejam:

Principal

```
import java.sql.*;
import static javax.swing.UIManager.getString;

public class Conectora {

    public static String nome;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            Statement atestamento;
            ResultSet resultado;

            String usuario = "postgres";
            String senha = "123";
            String endereco = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/ueer5";

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(endereco, usuario, senha);

            atestamento = con.createStatement();

            atestamento.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE codigo = 1;");

            resultado = atestamento.getResultSet();

            while (resultado.next()) {

                nome = resultado.getString(2);
            }

            System.out.println(nome);//fora do while

            con.close();

            System.out.println("Conexão bem-sucedida.");

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Conexão mal-sucedida.\n"+e);
        }

        System.out.println(nome);//fora do try-catch
    }        

}
```

Outra classe

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import Gertrudes.Conectora;
import static Gertrudes.Conectora.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Declaradora {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String aluno = null;
        String serie = "1º";
        String nascimento = "20/01/2001";
        String mae = "Beltrana de Tal";
        String pai = "Cicrano de Tal";
        String diretor = "Dirceu E. Torquato";

        Document dec = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        try{
            PdfWriter.getInstance(dec, new FileOutputStream("dec.pdf"));

            dec.open();
            Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("DECLARAÇÃO");
            titulo.setAlignment(1);
            titulo.setSpacingAfter(30);
            dec.add(titulo);

            Paragraph texto = new Paragraph("Declaro para os fins que se fizerem necessários que o (a) aluno (a) "+ aluno +" está matriculado (a) e cursando regularmente o  "+ serie +" ano do Ensino Fundamental neste estabelecimento de ensino no ano corrente.");
            texto.setAlignment(3);
            texto.setSpacingAfter(30);
            dec.add(texto);

            Paragraph dados = new Paragraph("Data de nascimento: "+ nascimento +"\nMãe: "+ mae +"\nPai:"+ pai );
            //dados.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            dados.setSpacingAfter(30);
            dec.add(dados);

            Paragraph assinatura = new Paragraph("____________________________\n" + diretor + "\nDiretor");
            assinatura.setAlignment(1);
            assinatura.setSpacingAfter(30);
            dec.add(assinatura);

            Paragraph local = new Paragraph("Agricolândia - PI, "+ new Date());
            local.setAlignment(2);
            //assinatura.setSpacingAfter(30);
            dec.add(local);

            dec.close();

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("dec.pdf"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Errooouu!"+ ex);
        }
        System.out.println("nome: "+nome+"\naluno: "+aluno);
    }
}
```

No caso, eu estava testando primeiramente passar apenas o nome do aluno.

Comment: Na chamada do método você passa como parâmetro o nome, no caso uma String, caso você chame o método e queira um retorno dentro do mesmo método, este deve retornar uma String, onde você colocar print...nome, você devia retorna-lo, n? só que ele está como void, então não retorna nada, seria algo como: `public String ...` então no retorno você colocar `return suastring`, então onde você o chama vc pega essa informação e a usa como quiser

Comment: Outro caso era deixar a variável nome como `static` assim você poderia acessa-la de qualquer classe, basta fazer  `String nome = minhaclasse.nomedaviaril` assim você a pegaria da outra classe sem precisar passa-la

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, cria uma classe aluno que será seu DTO e uma função na classe que conecta ao banco de dados que retorna esse aluno. Exemplo de Classe:

```
public class Aluno {

private String nomeAluno;
private int matriculaAluno;

public String getNomeAluno() {
    return nomeAluno;
}

public void setNomeAluno(String nomeAluno) {
    this.nomeAluno = nomeAluno;
}

public int getMatriculaAluno() {
    return matriculaAluno;
}

public void setMatriculaAluno(int matriculaAluno) {
    this.matriculaAluno = matriculaAluno;
}
```

E a o método na classe de consulta para retornar este:

```
private List<Aluno> buscaTodosOsAlunos() {
    // ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte.